# Get ViewChildren Template By Id

Tags: angular, angular9

In my component I get a list of its markup templates by using ViewChildren:

```
@ViewChildren(TemplateRef) private _templates: QueryList<TemplateRef<unknown>>;
```

In Angular8 I was not able to filter them by an Id, so i needed to look for an internal property - which was somehow a bit hacky:

```
let template = this._templates.find(t => (<any>t)._def.references[id]) : null;
```

Now, with Angular 9, this doesn't work anymore. I checked the object and found a new "hack":

```
this._templates.find(t => (<any>t)._declarationTContainer?.localNames?.includes(id)) : null;
```

But is there any new or clean solution for this scenario?

Still hoping for a solution that works without a custom Directive, eg. MatTab probably does something similar, too:

```
<mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        ...
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template matTabContent>
        ...
    </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your end goal here? What does the template look like, and what do you want a reference to?

Comment: The trailing `: null` seems weird and should give you a syntax error. Did this really ever work?

Comment: Hey, sorry, was pretty busy - hoped for someone knowing this issue, the following answer ist just perfect. The trailing `: null` was because of an allocation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A clean solution for your scenario is to create a `NgTemplateNameDirective` directive with `ng-template[name]` selector:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ng-template[name]'
})
export class NgTemplateNameDirective {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) { }
}
```

after that create templates like:

```
<ng-template name="t1"></ng-template>
<ng-template name="t2"></ng-template>
```

then query `NgTemplateNameDirective` instead of `TemplateRef`:

```
@ViewChildren(NgTemplateNameDirective) private _templates: QueryList<NgTemplateNameDirective>;
```

and finally search your template by name

```
getTemplateRefByName(name: string): TemplateRef<any> {
  const dir = this._templates.find(dir => dir.name === name);
  return dir ? dir.template : null
}
```

**Works fine in both view engines: ViewEngine and Ivy**.

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/5OGMZ08gP2Hpvk26pBDt?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Perfect! Just what I'm looking for! But is there maybe a chance to use the regular `#id`? would be even nicer.

Comment: @tris If you want to use regular `#id` then go with your hacky solutions otherwise create directive. Angular material does the same trick with templates

Comment: Ah, sure - just saw it wrong, they DO use a Directive, not an Id. Solution back on it, thank you :)