# How to get ng-template by @Input property in Angular

Tags: angular

I try to create component which should find `<ng-template>` by @Input property and returns it content.

Here is code of this component.

**template.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, TemplateRef,  ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-template',
  templateUrl: './template.component.html'
})
export class TemplateComponent {
  @Input() id: string;

  templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

**template.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="templateRef" [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef"></ng-container>

<ng-template id="1" #template1>
  <p>template 1 content</p>
</ng-template>

<ng-template id="2" #template2>
  <p>template 2</p>
</ng-template>
```

And here is an example of using of this component.

```
<h2>Template 1</h2>
<my-template id="template1"></my-template>

<h2>Template 2</h2>
<my-template id="template2"></my-template>
```

The problem is how to find specific template by it's id.

I try this way, but it doesn't work:

```
@ViewChild(this.id, { static: true }) templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Also I tried to get all templates and then find specific from the list, but it also doesn't work:

```
@ViewChildren(TemplateRef) templates: TemplateRef<any>[];

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.templateRef = this.templates.find(template => template.name === id);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-my-template-dynamic

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: So you wish to pass the id value to each child component?

Comment: Not exactly, I try to select specific ng-template by passing Id of this template to my component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution here:
[Get ViewChildren Template By Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191471/get-viewchildren-template-by-id)

I have created a simple directive and then use it to get template by id.

**TemplateIdDirective**

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ng-template[id]'
})
export class TemplateIdDirective {
  @Input() id: string;

  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) { }
}
```

**template.component.ts**

```
@ViewChildren(TemplateIdDirective) private templates: QueryList<TemplateIdDirective>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.templateRef = this.getTemplateRefById(this.templates, this.id);
}

getTemplateRefById(templates: QueryList<TemplateIdDirective>, id: string): TemplateRef<any> {
  const directive = templates.find(template => template.id === id);
  return directive ? directive.template : null;
}
```